# Convert Gollum (markdown) wiki to PDF

Tags: pdf, web-crawler, markdown, gollum-wiki

We have a wiki written in Markdown served up by Gollum. We'd like to PDF the current state of the wiki to make a "book".

All the files are .md on disk, or they can be browsed via HTTP/HTML. Is there a tool that can recursively traverse the wiki or filesystem and turn the markdown or HTML into a PDF? Preserving lists would be great.

Comment: Asking for "a tool" is OT on SO ... But you may be able to improve your question: what is the problem? Traversing your file system? Converting HTML to PDF can be googled (and will, in fact, point to SO solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Handling the links is the tricky part. You could easily feed all the files into pandoc to get a single pdf (if you give it multiple files it will concatenate them), but I don't know how it will handle inter-page links. Possibly you could fix this using a combination of generated tags and a combination of the  -A, -B and/or -H flags.